# Summing the product of combinations of matrix elements

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algorithms, permutations

I have a situation where I have an $NxN$ matrix $A$ where each element $a_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$. I would like to consider the set of all collections of elements such that each collection of $N$ elements contains one element from each column and one from each row. For each collection I would like to compute the product of the elements and then to compute the sum of these products over all of the collections in the set. For example, if $A$ is a $3x3$ matrix then I am interested in the quantity $a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}+a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2}+a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3}+a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1}+a_{1,3}a_{2,1}a_{3,2}+a_{1,3}a_{2,2}a_{3,1}$.

Are there any particularly efficient ways to compute this quantity for large matrices? Enumerating the different permutations and computing it recursively both become intractable for large $N$. An approximation that is true under certain conditions could also help. I would alternatively appreciate any terminology or the name of a related problem that would help point me down the right path. Thanks!

Comment: Try "matrix permanent"  . More generally, immanents might also be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed exactly the quantity that I'm interested in. I was able to find information on it easily now that I have the correct term.

Comment: You're welcome.  Requests of this level are more suited for math.stackexchange than for this forum. I recommend asking there if you have similar questions.